# hold values of dropdown using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

there are two drop downs naming country and state.....so how to hold the values whwn error occurs in the form.i have used ajax to list the state value

```
 <select name="country" onchange="getstate(this.value,'')">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <?php   $option="";
    $query="select * from tbl_country";
    $res=mysql_query($query);
    while ($country=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $country['id']; ?>"><?php echo $country['country']; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
    </select>
  <select id="state" >
</select>
```

/////ajax code///////

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getstate(id) {



    $.ajax({

        type : 'post',

        url : 'ajax.php',

        data : {

            act : 'get_state',

            country : id,



        },

        success : function(data) {

            data = data.replace(/\s*\n\s*/g, '');

            if (data) {



                document.getElementById('state').innerHTML = data;

            } else {



            }

            return true;

        }
    });

}
</script>
```

///////ajax.php/////

```
if($_REQUEST['act']=="get_state"){
    $statelist=array();
    $countryid=$_REQUEST['country'];

    $query="select * from tbl_state where id_country=".$countryid;
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $option.='<option value="">select</option>';
    while ($state=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $option.= '<option value="'.$state["state"].'">'.$state["state"].'</option>';
    }
    echo $option;

}
```

I want to hold both the values of country and state at the time of form submit(error occurs). how to do that?

Comment: what type of error occurs ?

Comment: i mean to say i want to hold the values when form submits.....for eg.when a field in a registration form remains unfilled then i have to hold the values